# How to use terraformer for querying Github Enterprise?

Tags: github, terraform, github-enterprise

I'm not able to say terraformer to use other url than https://api.github.com

Terraformer: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer

Terraform Github provider: https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github

It looks like that provider is supporting Github Enterprise by providing `export GITHUB_BASE_URL=` mechanism to provide different base_url.

But the behaviour of terraformer is not changed after.

```
$export GITHUB_BASE_URL=https://git.enterprise.com/

$terraformer import github --organizations=org --resources=repositories --token=***
```

2021/04/07 16:12:55 github importing organization org

2021/04/07 16:12:55 github importing... repositories

2021/04/07 16:12:56 GET **https://api.github.com**/orgs/bt/repos?per_page=100

Any advice, how to bypass this hardcoded value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
tc := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, ts)
```

here: [terraformer/providers/github/repositories.go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/blob/7c0dc227dd424030c5d179de5ed547a74afcdecf/providers/github/repositories.go#L37)

for this:

```
baseUrl := "https://_YOUR_GITHUB_ENTERPRISE_BAS_URL_/api/v3/"
client, _ := githubAPI.NewEnterpriseClient(baseUrl, baseUrl, tc)
```

The same for other resources like teams.go, members.go, ...

Comment: Terraformer v0.8.13 fix this in this PR https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/pull/871 by adding new commandline parameter for github service `./terraformer import github --owner=YOUR_ORGANIZATION --resources=repositories --base-url=https://your-enterprise-github-url`

Comment: Following PR to fix this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/pull/894